# Describe relative angles between points (like driving directions)

Tags: php, driving-directions, map-directions

I have a list of points with x, y coordinates. I know how to get the distance between points with `sqrt(pow($x2 - $x1, 2) + pow($y2 - $y1, 2))` and the angle between points with  `atan2(y1 - y2, x1 - x2)`.

How can I calculate the relative angle between the points (left, right, straight)? So, if I'm at point 1, what is the relative direction to point 2, then 2 to 3, 3 to 4, etc...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: There is no "relative direction" between points.  Points have no direction associated with them.  You can only find the distance between then, or the absolute angle between a vector with the root at the origin.  If you want a "relative direction", you'd need to define a vector between the current point and the previous, and then get difference in angle between the absolute angle of that relative vector and the absolute angle of the vector form the current point to the next point...

Comment: I'm honestly not sure what you mean by the angle between points, as it will always be 180 degrees (as straight line). But what you really need is the angle between two *lines*. You need a direction to start with, so call point 1 to point 2 "straight". Then you can calculate the angle between the two lines (point 1 - point 2) and (point 2 - point 3).

Answer (score 2):

Call [`atan2($y1 - $y2, $x1 - $x2)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.atan2.php)

If it's between π/2 and 3π/2, it's straight.
If it's more than 3π/2 or less than -3π/2, it's a left turn.
If it's between -π/2 and π/2, it's a right turn.

Here is a diagram:

```
 {3π/2}-------{π/2}-------{π/4}
      | +-----[ +y]-----+ | 
      | |               | | 
      | |               | | 
    {π} [-x]  [0,0]  [+x] {0} 
      | |               | | 
      | |               | | 
      | +-----[ -y]-----+ |
{-3π/2}-------{-π/2}------{-π/4}
```

Comment: I'm already doing that. I just need to understand how to interpret the results, I guess...

Comment: Doesn't that assume you start facing between 3π/2 and π/2? If you started facing 0 then it's a whole different ball game. Assuming this is akin to a SatNav system then the turn direction can only be determined from x2,y2 onward as x1,y1 to x2,y2 is required to establish orientation.

Comment: @Lazarus: You're right; you should look at the difference between the angles.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the angle from point 2 to 1, and point 2 to 3, it's just a matter of `angle_to_3 - angle_to_1`,  (or angle to next minus angle to previous) which you know how to calculate with atan2, or am I mistaken? Left /right / straight is just rounding the result. If you want to do it the hard way you can rotate your points so the angle from 2 to 1 is 0, but that seems unnecessarily convoluted.

Answer (score 0):

Given your example of driving directions, the concept of left/right/straight only make sense in relation to the current direction of travel. This is why SatNav units start with the first turn or "Please proceed to the planned route" when you are off it's map rather than an immediate turn left/right/etc...

If you know the angle of x1,y1 to x2,y2 then you can give an indication of the relative direction for the next point using the angle x2,y2 to x3,y3. If the next angle is greater then it'll probably be a left turn, less is a right turn and within a certain margin around the first angle it'll be straight on.